# Android 4.1 - RTSP using VideoView and MediaController

Tags: android, android-videoview, rtsp, rtp, mediacontroller

Developing a simple app to play a RTSP stream on Android 4.1, but unable to do so

**Update**

I am able Able to play if I use BigBuckBunny_115k.mov

```
Uri video = Uri.parse("rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov");
```

***BUT 
I tried with lot of RTSP streams [mentioned here](http://roku.cherritech.com/cherri_grid/RTSP.txt) and [here](http://channelshoes.sextgem.com/Streaming/Live%20Tv/102%20IlIlIlIlIlIlIlI), but none worked :(***

****Problem: I could not see any stream on my phone, only black screen is visible.. After some time, a dialog box appears "Can't play this video". I tried with many RTSP streams, but same result, so is it issue with all the streams mentioned? Or .sdp is not parsed properly? Is something missing in the code snippet? ****

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video);
        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
        mediaController.setMediaPlayer(videoView);

        Uri video = Uri.parse("rtsp://ss1c6.idc.mundu.tv:554/prf0/cid_29.sdp");
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        videoView.setVideoURI(video);
        videoView.start();
    }
```

```
<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/video"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
```

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.rdx.livetv.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

```
10-08 17:53:03.674: D/libEGL(22488): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
10-08 17:53:03.682: D/libEGL(22488): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
10-08 17:53:03.682: D/libEGL(22488): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
10-08 17:53:03.775: D/OpenGLRenderer(22488): Enabling debug mode 0
10-08 17:53:03.783: D/MediaPlayer(22488): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
10-08 17:53:03.900: D/MediaPlayer(22488): getMetadata
10-08 17:53:06.596: D/dalvikvm(22488): GC_CONCURRENT freed 102K, 2% free 11074K/11207K, paused 14ms+3ms, total 42ms
10-08 17:55:05.799: E/MediaPlayer(22488): error (1, -2147483648)
10-08 17:55:05.799: E/MediaPlayer(22488): Error (1,-2147483648)
10-08 17:55:05.799: D/VideoView(22488): Error: 1,-2147483648
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I analyzed the streams given in these links using [openRTSP](http://www.live555.com/openRTSP/).

"openRTSP" is a command-line program that can be used to open, stream, receive, and (optionally) record media streams that are specified by a RTSP URL - i.e., an URL that begins with rtsp://

Using this utility, I found that most of the SDP files mentioned had issues, and this is the reason for the issues coming in the application.

Comment: Is it related to Android development?

Comment: @Rohit Then , could you please categories those as working and non-working who need like me.

Answer (score 7):

another good solution for playing RTSP, using the native player.

```
mediaURL = "rtsp://192.168.0.119/Bolt.ts" 
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(mediaURL));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: This didn't play the videos correctly on my device (Galaxy Tab Active). In one case with a `.mkv` file it only played the audio and then in another case using a `.ts` file it just said `Unable to play video`.