# android unable to play .sdp file from videoview?

Tags: android, android-videoview

I am making an application in which i am using videoview. I have following error.

1.I have a videoview in which i am playing video from "rtsp://cdn.m.yupptv.tv/liveorigin/we2"
and it is working.

2.Now when i am going to play video from this url "rtsp://192.168.13.77:8086/stream.sdp" , so its not working & it prompt me the dialog "can't play this video".

3.is there any issue from videoview to play .sdp file ??

here is my source code

```
 public class Demo extends Activity
  {
private static ProgressDialog progressDialog;

String videourl;
VideoView videoView ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.video);
    videourl = Constant.URL;

    videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video_View);

    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Demo.this, "", "Buffering video...",true);
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);


    PlayVideo();
}

private void PlayVideo()
{
    try
    {   
        getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(Demo.this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);        

        Uri video = Uri.parse(videourl);          
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        videoView.setVideoURI(video);
        videoView.requestFocus();           
        videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener()
        {

            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)
            {                
                progressDialog.dismiss();  
                videoView.start();
            }
        });

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        System.out.println("Video Play Error :"+e.toString());
        finish();
    }

}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();

    finish();
    Intent i = new Intent(Demo.this,GetURL.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

}
please help me..,i am serching for this solution from 2 days,..,but not getting proper solution.Thanks in advance..:)

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19247772/android-4-1-rtsp-using-videoview-and-mediacontroller

Comment: ok..,thanku.. i try,,,:)