# android Videoview not playing .sdp files what should i do?

Tags: android, android-videoview, live-streaming

I am making live tv channel streaming app.
But when i try to play the .sdp files in the android videoview it gives the error that "Sorry can't play this video".But it is playing .mp4 and .3gp videos successfully.
What should i do.I googled alot but in vain.

```
String VideoURL = "rtsp://pull.newclear.tv/live/livestream2_160p";
//"rtsp://pull.newclear.tv/live/livestream2_160p";
//.sdp links are also giving same error
//links of above type are not working
```

This is my code for videoview

```
 MediaController mediacontroller = new MediaController(
 VideoViewActivity.this);
 mediacontroller.setAnchorView(videoview);
 // Get the URL from String VideoURL
 Uri video = Uri.parse(VideoURL);
 videoview.setMediaController(mediacontroller);
videoview.setVideoURI(video);
```

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19247772/android-4-1-rtsp-using-videoview-and-mediacontroller

Comment: Actually i have to use videoview in my app.It is a must from the boss.